# Test-Driven Development with Python -- chapter 6

Tags: python, django, tdd

```
def test_saving_a_POST_request(self):

        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = "POST"
        request.POST['item_text'] = "A new list item"
        response = new_list(request)
        # response = self.client.post('lists/new', {'item_text': "A new list item"})
        new_item = Item.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')
```

This is the method used to test post response of the new_list view. It works fine when i use HttpRequest(), it throws error when i tried to use inbuilt client to post(the commented line) the data rather than HttpRequest.

The error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_saving_a_POST_request (lists.tests.NewListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prabhath/PycharmProjects/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 95, in test_saving_a_POST_request
    self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think there is a problem with how i use the client to post data. This is the [link](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch06.html#_a_test_class_for_new_list_creation) for the section in textbook that i was reading. Any help is appreciated.

Django -- 1.9.5,
python -- 3.5

Comment: If you get an error, you should say what it is.

Comment: Could you try using `/lists/new/` instead of `lists/new` (note the leading slash) in your client call?

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I defined a url which starts with lists and ends with url     url(r'^lists/new$', views.new_list, name='new_list'). But i tried it did not work.

Comment: As @Joey said in the comment, **note the leading slash**. It should be `response = self.client.post('/lists/new', {'item_text': "A new list item"})`.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes i did but it did not work i got then same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your view's URL is not being referenced correctly. You most likely want to use Django's built-in URL resolution methods instead of hard coding the url, `lists/new`, like you have. This would make your test case look something like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Item


class ItemTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_saving_a_POST_request(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse_lazy('new_list'), {'item_text': "A new list item"})
        new_item = Item.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')
```